# Why does Hibernate transaction not update my database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having an issue with my login class. If a user unsuccessfully attempts to login with a username then that user account should be disabled. At runtime there are no errors but nothing changes in my database. Am I doing something wrong with updating my database through Hibernate, I thought I could just use my UserBean.class to access properties, change them and then commit the Hibernate transaction?

Here is my LoginDAO.class:

```
package com.sga.app.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.FlushMode;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContext;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.owasp.encoder.Encode;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

import com.sga.app.beans.UserBean;
import com.sga.app.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import com.sga.app.security.LoginFailureEventListener;
import com.sga.app.security.XssRequestWrapper;

@Component("loginDAO")
@Transactional
@Configuration
public class LoginDAO implements
    ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent> {

private int loginAttemptsThreshold;
private int failedLoginAttempts;
private static Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(LoginFailureEventListener.class);
private static Session session;
private Criteria criteria;
private String username;
private boolean enabled;
private String forename;
private String authority;
private XssRequestWrapper xssReqWrapper;
private PreparedStatement prepStmtUsers;
private PreparedStatement prepStmtAuthorities;
private String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/sgaWebApp@localhost:1521/XE";
private String updateUsersStatement = "insert into users (username, password) 
  values (:username, :password)";
private String updateAuthoritiesStatement = "insert into authorities (username, 
  authority) values (:username, :authority)";

@Bean
public LoginDAO loginDAO() {
    return new LoginDAO();
}

public void setLoginAttemptsThreshold(int threshold) {
    this.loginAttemptsThreshold = threshold;
}

@Transactional
public void loginUser(UserBean user, BindingResult result) {

    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        // clean out any possible XSS injection
        String cleanUsernameValueInput = cleanOutXSSVulnerabilities("j_username");
        String cleanPasswordValueInput = cleanOutXSSVulnerabilities("j_password");
        // OWASP encoding
        String safeUsername = Encode.forHtml(cleanUsernameValueInput);
        prepStmtUsers.setString(1, safeUsername);
        String safePassword = Encode.forHtml(cleanPasswordValueInput);
        prepStmtUsers.setString(2, safePassword);
        prepStmtAuthorities.setString(1, safeUsername);
        String safeUserAuthority = Encode.forHtml(user.getAuthority());
        prepStmtAuthorities.setString(2, safeUserAuthority);
        // execute login process
        prepStmtUsers = conn.prepareStatement(updateUsersStatement);
        prepStmtAuthorities = conn
                .prepareStatement(updateAuthoritiesStatement);
        prepStmtUsers.executeUpdate();
        prepStmtAuthorities.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AccessDeniedException accessDenied) {
        accessDenied.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String cleanOutXSSVulnerabilities(String input) {
    return xssReqWrapper.cleanXSS(input);
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(
        AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event) {
    if (event.getException().getClass()
            .equals(UsernameNotFoundException.class)) {
        return;
    }
    // print registration attempts to log file for security investigation if
    // required
    logger.info("Registration attempt failed: " + event.getException());
    logger.info("Registration attempt number: " + event.getTimestamp());
    String userId = event.getAuthentication().getName();
    logger.info("FAILED LOGIN ATTEMPT NUMBER "
            + recordLoginAttempts(userId));
    recordLoginAttempts(userId);
    if (recordLoginAttempts(userId) >= loginAttemptsThreshold) {
        lockoutUser(userId);
    }
}

private int recordLoginAttempts(String userId) {
    failedLoginAttempts++;
    return failedLoginAttempts;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private ArrayList<UserBean> getUserAccountDetails(String input) {
    ArrayList<UserBean> returnValues = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
    session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
    session.beginTransaction();
    criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBean.class);
    List<UserBean> retrievedUser = criteria.add(
            Restrictions.like("username", input)).list();
    for (UserBean userDetails : retrievedUser) {
        logger.debug("USERNAME INSIDE THE GET USER ACCOUNT DETAILS METHOD: "
                + userDetails.getUsername());
        logger.debug("AUTHORITY INSIDE THE GET USER ACCOUNT DETAILS METHOD: "
                + userDetails.getAuthority());
        returnValues.add(userDetails);
    }
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return returnValues;
}

private void lockoutUser(String userId) {
    ArrayList<UserBean> userAccountValues = getUserAccountDetails(userId);
    session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
    ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
    session.beginTransaction();
    for (UserBean user : userAccountValues) {
        username = user.getUsername();
        forename = user.getForename();
        enabled = user.getEnabled();
        authority = user.getAuthority();
        logger.debug("USERNAME: " + username);
        logger.debug("FORENAME: " + forename);
        logger.debug("ENABLED BEFORE CHANGE: " + enabled);
        user.setEnabled(false);
        logger.debug("AUTHORITY BEFORE CHANGE: " + authority);
        user.setAuthority("BLOCKED");
    }
    session.flush();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    logger.debug("ENABLED AFTER CHANGE: " + enabled);
    logger.debug("AUTHORITY AFTER CHANGE: " + authority);
    session.close();
    ManagedSessionContext.unbind(HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory());
    }

}
```

Comment: I originally called onApplicationEvent() within my loginUser() if result.hasErrors() in an attempt to trigger the lock-out process but no updates to database were made.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code. You are mixing concerns, you are trying to use `@Transactional` but are working very hard in your code to make thatt impossible to work. For starters don't mix `@Configuration` and `@Component` (which should be `@Repository` imho) those are different concerns and shouldn't be in a single class. You are using spring and transaction management so let spring do the heavy lifting use `getCurrentSession` instead.

Comment: Your code is also flawed as you are keeping state (i.e. `failedLoginAttempts` ) if you have 10 users each trying to login and fail one of them will immediately be locked out as this counter is shared. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this class but I would first suggest you to read how Spring can help you and clean up your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be invoking `openSession` in that manner. I would highly suggest you rewrite the method to not do any "session" related work at all.  Let Spring handle it, especially since you are already using `@Transactional`.

Either way, in the lockoutUser() method, the users you find, aren't bound to the session that gets created after it.

`ArrayList<UserBean> userAccountValues = getUserAccountDetails(userId);
  session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();`

So, later in the method when you update the user instances of that ArrrayList, the session doesn't realize that the user instances are to be persisted because the session was never tracking them.

Try to have only one session per thread. Each method can have its own transaction, but we rarely come across situations where we need more than one session in a thread. This doesn't seem to be that kind of a situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
session.flush();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

Try to delete `session.flush();` or put it after `session.getTransaction().commit();` may work.

Comment: Not sure what's the point of doing a flush after commit.  But I do agree, that the flush is not needed if a commit is doing done.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't appear that you call `session.save(Object)` or `session.update(Object)`.